# Update ng-Highcharts into Html table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts-ng

I'm looking for a way to get html table from angular Highcharts. I know it is possible to extract data from Html table to display a chart.   But opposite seems more complex. Could you help me please ?

EDIT: If someone is looking for : http://a----.github.io/highcharts-export-clientside/   It works for me.

Comment: You can get Data from highchart Object. Highchart draws `series` and `categories`. I hope you need these two arrays. For more information you should see the highchart documentation.

Comment: Yes I know i can get series and categories.  In fact I have an array of chart . And for each chart I have a button which switch the "type" of the chart..( pie, line , bar etc..) . But I dont know how to manage to update with html table by the same way.